# Linux Python process with visible console window

Tags: python, linux, shell, process, output

I have a question about Python on Linux.  I have a Python application that currently runs on Windows.  The application controls some hardware, and each hardware control application runs in it's own process, which in turn sometimes start processes of their own. The processes communicate with named pipes, named mutexes, and named memory-mapped files to the main control process, but each application process has its own console window.  This allows the user to select the window for one application process, representing one hardware item, and view what it's doing.  It also allows a simple "print" to produce debug statements on the window for that process. On Windows this is easy because either os.startfile or subprocess.popen can run a python script in a separate process, in a new console window, and capturing "print" output in that window.  The main process starts all the application processes and then minimizes the windows, making it easy for the  user to select one (or more) for viewing.  The application processes write log files when they are done, but having a console window for each one allows viewing of progress and messages in real time.

I need to make a linux version of this and I'm running into issues.  I can't figure out how to make Linux open an application in a separate, visible, process window.  If I use subprocess.popen with shell=True, I get a separate process but no visible window.  If I set stdout=subprocess.PIPE, the application isn't in a separate process, but uses the main process window for printing, and incidentally hangs the main process until it's done (this is disasterous in my application).  I found a workaround where I open the application process with shell=True, and the application process then creates a named pipe and opens its own GUI (using shell=True) for output display.  But this means I have to change all the print statements in the application processes to go to the named pipe, which is a huge amount of work.  Plus, it would be nice (but not essential) if the Windows and Linux versions looked the same in how the windows appear.

Is there a way, in Python, on Linux, to start a new Python process in an open, visible window that will capture "print" statements?  Or am I trying to do something Linux doesn't support?  I'd rather not change everything to sockets - it would probably be easier to use the GUI and named  pipe method than to do that.

Thanks for any answers or insight.

Comment: You're just using `os.startfile("path/to/python/script.py")` and rely on it to open a visible window? That's bad design. What if the user's default application for running python files _doesn't_ show a visible window? This is exactly the problem you're encountering on linux. You should manually open a console window and execute the python script inside it, for example with `xterm -e python path/to/script.py`.

Comment: With regards to your workaround, can't you do something like `print = functools.partial(print, file=f)`

Comment: This looks like it will work, I wrote a simple script to check it out and appears to be working.  Only problem is that my paths have spaces in the names, so I need to do something like os.popen("xterm -e python " + os.getcwd() + "/" + "script.py startupprameter"), where the getcwd result is going to have spaces.  I tried using doublequotes, which works in windows, but doesn't seem to work in Linux.

Comment: As for the os.startfile, this is automated test equipment, so I control what the associations are.

Comment: To get around escaping problems, you can choose to use the `subprocess` module instead of `os` or use [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

Comment: I'm still stuck on this.  I see all kinds of examples on the Internet where spaces in path names are handled with 'r or doublequotes (in Windows) but in my case, the pathname can't be hard-coded.  I have to use os.getcwd or something to get the path name.  I can make this work consistently with os.system or subprocess.popen as long as there are no spaces in the directory names.  I've tried shlex and lists and doublequotes and os.path and "".join. But I just cannot make this work with spaces in the path.  Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Well, right after I posted that, I figured out the answer (amazing how that works).  I walk through the result of os.getcwd and replace all spaces with "\ ".  Then it works.  Although I'll have to use popen, as os.system blocks.